# How to calculate and expose a single value for external/remote use

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, cron, content-management-system

I have a program with users that will be pledging to walk a certain number of miles. I'd like to calculate the sum of those miles and display the proportional progress (current sum vs. planned total) as a progress meter. The database that will store those submission values cannot be directly referenced by the host server that the form will live on because of connection incompatibilities.

The database storing the submissions is Azure, the site is WordPress on top of Pantheon. I think the best way to proceed would be to create a cron job that connects to and queries Azure to find the sum of the pledged miles and writes a file accessible by the WordPress site to fill the progress meter appropriately based on the number of pledged miles. This seems like an inefficient approach but I need to connect the systems indirectly, and having it run as a separate task seems like the best way to reduce page load time by not having a middle step that needs to reference a file that needs to make a calculation.

Should I be trying to do it this way? What kind of file or location should the cron job write to?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a quick REST API in .NET and then a plugin in Wordpress that makes a GET call and retrieves the data each time the page loads or set up a cron job to get that data and store it in the MySQL DB